# A regexp that will grab anything in quotes + the word draft within the quotes? only the quotes with the word Draft

Tags: regex

A regexp that will grab anything in quotes + the word draft within the quotes. So it will look for the word Draft and upon finding it grab everything in front of it and behind it within the quotes. For example:

1) "earth is beautiful"

2) "My Second Draft"

In the above examples the regexp will only grab the second example, highlighting everything within the quotes. How can this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Language is JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
\"[^\"]*(d|D)(r|R)(a|A)(f|F)(t|T)[^\"]*\"
```

Explanation:

- `\"` - match the `"` character
- `[^\"]*` - match any sequence of characters, as long as no characters in the sequence are the `"` character
- `(d|D)(r|R)(a|A)(f|F)(t|T)` - match the word "draft", case-insensitive
- `[^\"]*` - match any sequence of characters, as long as no characters in the sequence are the `"` character
- `\"` - match the `"` character

Depending on the language you're using, you should be able to get rid of the `(d|D)(r|R)(a|A)(f|F)(t|T)` sequence and replace it with `draft` as long as you indicate that the Regex should be treated as case-insensitive.

Since you're using Javascript, your Regex literal would look like this:

```
/\"[^\"]*draft[^\"]*\"/i
```

Comment: Kinda works, kinda Doesn't: it grabbed this whole thing:
"1 - Draft","2 - Draft", "fake", " Fake Draft 2",

It shouldn't have grabbed "fake", you think it can be improved?

thanks though

Comment: @Ahmed - I've modified my answer slightly, see if that works better for you.

Comment: WoW Donut U made it work man, thank you so much, i was going crazy over this for a long time, thanks !!!

Comment: @Donut With the option `i`, you can tell the regex to be case insensitive. It would be much easier to read, understand, maintain and modify.

Comment: @Jean Thanks, I was holding off on mentioning that specifically since the OP did not indicate which language he was using. He's since mentioned that he's using Javascript, and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: works like a charm thanks mates n my bad for not specifying what language i was working with.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern should work for you

```
/\"((draft.*)|(.*draft.*)|(.*draft))\"/Ui
```